# Strange YouTube video cannot be downloaded

Tags: video, download, youtube

I'm trying to download [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSPFB-xF5iM) video from `YouTube`. I have tried [FlashGot](https://flashgot.net) and [Video DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/) as Firefox extensions and a couple of online services which provide downloading videos from `YouTube` without success.

The strange thing is I can download any part of tutorial (total of 14 parts) except parts [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSPFB-xF5iM),[4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59rEMnKWoS4) and [8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bShqyf-hDfg). When I download those parts the video has a single frame of picture (no videos in fact) and related sound.

How can I download those parts?

Comment: Video DownloadHelper worked just fine for me for part 2.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Thanks. Problem was `VLC` 2.2.2 and Totem plays the video. Still wondering what is wrong. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I'm running 2.2.4 and it works. You could self answer the question for the benefit of any future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the hint from [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)'s comment I found that the problem is really with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) 2.2.2 on `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` and other players (i.e. Totem) can play the video. Still VLC plays any other video very well including other parts of the tutorial.